# Newsletter subscribe form using ajax jQuery & xml as database

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, frontend

I would like to add newsletter subscription but i would like to use ajax, jQuery, xml as database rather than a conventional database.

I would like to complete package ( including all necessary files like ajax, jQuery script, php to save in xml)

I know about jQuery plugin but that is not much of help & I need quick & easy solution of this

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not really the sort of question that should be asked on Stack Overflow. You should try and work it out for yourself and post here if you are have specific problems. Not I need code.

Comment: "I need quick & easy solution" without showing further research effort makes people here not try to help you. Just a warning. Try to show us what you have reached so far.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the XML via JQuery, you can use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). When saving XML via PHP, you can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: Thanks Wayne for your answer but I would like complete example with all necessary files so i just deploy it I am not expert in php or ajax

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this free plugin](https://github.com/Pantherius/Simple-Signup-Form)
It is contains the features you need, except the XML to Database. Use the recommendation above to extend the plugin with the XML feature. (SimpleXML)